# How do I resize an image with Java?

Tags: java, image-processing, image-resizing

I have a bunch of 48x48 images that I need 16x16 versions of, and instead of storing the 16x16 versions, I want to resize them on the fly. My current code looks like this (model.icon() returns the 48x48 image):

```
Icon icon = model.icon();
Image image = new BufferedImage(icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
return new ImageIcon(image.getScaledInstance(16, 16, Image.SCALE_AREA_AVERAGING));
```

Unfortunately, when this code is run, I get a 16x16 black square instead of the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
ImageIcon icon = model.icon();
Image image = new BufferedImage(icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
image.getGraphics().drawImage(icon.getImage(), 0, 0, 16, 16, null);
return new ImageIcon(image);
```

Comment: Er, the only problem is that `Graphics.drawImage()` takes an `Image` instead of an `Icon`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct - I've justed updated my code - you need to call icon.getImage(), as you've probably realised from andrewmu's answer :)

Answer (score 3):

You need more information than just the Icon reference. You need access to the actual image. You're new image is a black square because you never set the source if the image (i.e. you create a new black image and then scale the empty image).

Comment: Thank you, but how do I transfer the image data from the icon to the image?

Answer (score 2):

You are not putting the Icon into the Image.  If icon is an `ImageIcon`, then you can do:

```
..
Graphics2D g2 = image.createGraphics();
g2.drawImage(icon.getImage(), 0, 0, 16, 16, null);
g2.dispose();
return new ImageIcon(image);
```

Comment: Also, to improve the appearance, before you draw the image into g2, you can do: `g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHint.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC)` to get better quality output.

Comment: Thanks. This answer + the answer I marked as the solution helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method also for seizing images

```
 public static void resize(final String inputImagePath, final String outputImagePath, final int scaledWidth, final int scaledHeight) throws IOException {
    final File inputFile = new File(inputImagePath);
    final BufferedImage inputImage = ImageIO.read(inputFile);

    final BufferedImage outputImage = new BufferedImage(scaledWidth, scaledHeight, inputImage.getType());

    final Graphics2D g2d = outputImage.createGraphics();
    g2d.drawImage(inputImage, 0, 0, scaledWidth, scaledHeight, null);
    g2d.dispose();

    final String formatName = outputImagePath.substring(outputImagePath.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);

    ImageIO.write(outputImage, formatName, new File(outputImagePath));
}
```